# Magento 2 Get Product collections by specific attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes

I'm trying to get product collection by custom attribute "Age"
Age is a Dropdown attribute

Please help me to get this solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the collection by `attribute code` and `Option ID`.

You can use `addAttributeToFilter` for collection filter by using a custom attribute.

```
protected $productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory  $productCollectionFactory

){
     $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
}

$productcollection = $this->productCollectionFactory
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute code', 'option id');
```

Answer (score 0):

For the drop-down attribute, We can filter using drop-down option ID instead of Label.

Your code is like below.

```
$productcollection = $this->_productCollection
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('age', 18)
    ->load();
```

Comment: Please update code to load option Id by option label, then it will be useful