# Magento2: How to apply two sorting one magento default one and other sort by attributes?

Tags: magento2, product, sort

I want to sort my products by attributes : that is working fine but I want to apply two sort together , like sort by name asc and sort by attributes asc also

How can I implement this ?.

Based on answer added below code in toolbar.php (where hour is input value attributes, i want to show all products with hour value as 320), but it seems not working

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

```
class Toolbar
{
    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        $result = $proceed($collection);

        $subject->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('hour','320'); 
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: hour is product Attribute ??

Comment: Please print this whole collection and see Your attribute is there or not ?? You need to filert attribute like other way.

Comment: print_R( $collection);  ->> give memory error

Comment: Use print_r($collection->getData()); to print collection

Comment: For attribute filter try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226897/magento-2-get-product-collections-by-specific-attribute

Answer (score 0):

> **I add two option in sort by drop down for product price (high to low) and (low to hight).**

[image]

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <!-- for add option in sort by drop down -->
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="addOptions" type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Plugin\Model\Config" />
    </type>

   <!-- for do process for sort by option vise  -->
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="addPriceFilter" type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
    </type>

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Plugin/Model**

**Config.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Plugin\Model;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Config
{
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;   
    }

    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
    {
        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
        $currencySymbol = $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getCurrencySymbol();

        //Remove specific default sorting options
        //unset($options['position']);
        //unset($options['name']);
        unset($options['price']); // here i remove price option

        //Changing label
        //$customOption['position'] = __('Relevance');

        //New sorting options
        $customOption['price_desc'] = __($currencySymbol.' (High -> Low)');
        $customOption['price_asc'] = __($currencySymbol.' (Low -> High)');

        //Merge default sorting options with custom options
        $options = array_merge($customOption, $options);

        return $options;
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Plugin/Product/ProductList**

**Toolbar.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{
    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        $result = $proceed($collection);

        if ($currentOrder) {
            if ($currentOrder == 'price_desc') {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'desc');
            } elseif ($currentOrder == 'price_asc') {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

> here we can apply our custom filter also like custom attribute value or some other product value. by using **addFieldToFilter()**.

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Please check and update me.

Comment: tried below code but it seems not working


class Toolbar
{
    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        $result = $proceed($collection);
  
  $subject->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('hour','320'); 
        return $result;
    }
}

Comment: hour is text attribute

Comment: you must follow above Toolbar.php in which you need to check your parameter if condition.

Comment: please add your file in question for more details